# How to set up the root directory for apache2 Server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache

Im trying to publish my website for the first time (complete newbie in servers). Im using apache2 and the app is built with node/react/express.

The index.js file is inside myapp/packages/hotel/src.

what I did:

1. changed the root folder in /000-default.conf to "var/www/html/myapp/packages/hotel/src"
2. deleted the existing html folder with `sudo rm -r html`
3. made the git clone command `sudo git clone www.xyz123.. html`

When i open the website, there is "index of / " and the directories. The index of doesent even point to the src folder, its still inside the main directory.

What did i miss? It should load the index.js

Answer (score 0):

Re. 1: Use an absolute path:

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp/packages/hotel/src

Re. 3: Use git archive instead of clone as you don't want the .git directory to be served.  If your intention was for index.js to be an app that runs on the server, then you want to use node.js instead of apache2 to serve it.

Comment: the index.js starts the app wchich runs on node. 
Does that mean i cant host it on the apache server?

Comment: I think you are confused.  Why do you want to introduce apache2 into the mix?  node.js is a web server so it can serve content to your client directly.  You can certainly tell apach2 to proxy requests to node.js.  You can also tell apache to serve static files (i.e. images) of your project.  I don't think Apache2 does anything with your index.js other than wrapping a header around and serve it as is to the client.

Comment: i want to deploy my app on aws beacause it would be for free for 1 year.
Now i am following a course to deploy the app on aws. the second chapter is about how to publish a simple app on apache